What happened to this clove of garlic?
I'm not sure this is about cooking, but since it is about food, and what I'm asking about looks similar to what could have been a deliberate process, I thought I'd ask here.
The following two cloves come from the same bulb of garlic:

The right one is normal, the left one is somewhat spungy, slightly shrunk (it was loose in its skin) and smelling quite good (of garlic), but clearly something happened to it. There are no signs of rot or fungus. From the outside (before peeling) I did notice the skin was a bit loose, and at the bottom, where the root enters the clove, it was a bit discolored.
Does anyone know what happened here? Could this have been eaten safely?

@Tinkeringbell It is exactly that, thank you!
